# assign column names to the output of Series.str.extract()

Tags: python, pandas

Im using

```
df[colname].str.extract(regex)
```

to parse a column of strings into several columns. I'd like to be able to assign the column names at the same time, something like:

```
df[colname].str.extract(regex, columns=cnames)
```

where:

```
cnames = ['col1','col2','col3']
regex = r'(sometext\w)_(aa|bb)_(\d+-\d)'
```

Its possible with a clunky construction like:

```
df[colname].str.extract(regex).rename(columns = dict(zip(range(len(cnames)),cnames)))
```

Or else I could embed the column names in the regex as named groups, so the regex changes to:

```
regex = r'(?P<col1>sometext\w)_(?P<col2>aa|bb)_(?P<col3>\d+-\d)'
```

Am i missing something here, is there a simpler way?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done with embedding the names into the regex is a correct way of doing this. It states to do this in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html).

Your first solution using `.rename()` would not be robust if you had some columns with the names `0`, `1` and `2` already.

IMO the regex solution is the best but you could start to use something like `.pipe()` to implement a function in this way. However, as you will see, it starts to get messy when you do not want the same regex.

```
def extract_colnames(df, column, sep, cnames, drop_col=True):
    if drop_col:
        drop_col = [column]
    else:
        drop_col = []
    regex = '(?P<' + ('>.*)' + sep + '(?P<').join(cnames) + '>.*)'
    return df.join(df.loc[:, column].str.extract(regex, expand=True)).drop(drop_col, axis=1)

cnames = ['col1','col2','col3']
data = data.pipe(extract_colnames, column='colname',
                 sep='_', cnames=cnames, drop_col=True)
```

Comment: thanks for that -- its a handy function, i might end up using it!